# Genymotion Android emulator laggy on Macbook

Tags: macos, android-emulator, genymotion

I've been using genymotion for android react-native development but the emulator is so mind numbingly slow compared to the xcode ios emulator.

**mbp specs**

```
2.5ghz i7
16gb ram
intel iris plus 640
500gb ssd
```

**genymotion specs**

```
genymotion 3.0.0
google pixel emulator
processors 4
memory size 4096
virtual box 5.2.22
```

I had virtual box 6.x before but found a stack thread suggesting downgrading to the recommended version but it didn't fix anything.

The emulator works fine and boots relatively quick - all the animations however are very laggy and make it a pain to use

Looking for any recommendations, thanks

**edit:** I've tried reducing processors to 2 as virtual box was attempting to use 4 (default) but I have a dual core laptop, performance increased slightly - but still far off from the ios emulator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using an older version of Android? I heard reports of users finding the latest versions (especially Android 9.0) to be slow on macOS. This should be fixed in Genymotion Desktop 3.1.0.

Comment: This did the trick. My app was targetting API 27/28 so I never tried 26 (8.0) but it seems to run fine and is 100x faster. Thank you